# Need to htaccess redirect all urls from old subdomain to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In the root the code already working (for example):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.co.uk [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.NEW111NEW.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**Now I need to redirect a subdomain (like):**

from:
https://info.oldsite.co.uk/blog/some-blog-post-a

to:
https://info.NEW111NEW.com/blog/some-blog-post-a

I tried - 1 (not working):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^info.oldsite.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://info.NEW111NEW.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Also tried - 2 (not working):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(info\.)?oldsite\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://info.NEW111NEW.com/blog/$1 [R=302,L]
```

---Update---

When tried - 3 (its working partly):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^info\.oldsite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://info.new.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Here
https://info.oldsite.co.uk/dsadasdsad
is going to
https://info.new.com.co.uk/%60https://info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/%60https:/info.new.com.com/blog/blog/fsdfdsfsd%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60%60

AND
https://info.oldsite.co.uk/blog/dsadasdsad
is going to
https://info.new.com.com//blog/dsadasdsad (almost working but a double slash "//" here)

Comment: Try checking if your htaccess file is enabled OR not. Put a DUMMY LINE eg: `--------------------` in your htaccess at the top, save it and then hit ANY URL if you get **500 internal error** then it means its enabled if NOT then it means its not enabled, kindly do check this and let us know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes its 500, after added the "----------" in the htaccess file. By the way, thanks for the trick.

Comment: Change line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://info.new.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]` **TO** `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://info.new.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]` once in your last set of code and try once.

Comment: Do you have any other rules apart from shown ones in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^info\.oldsite\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://info.new.com%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

So, the `info.oldsite.co.uk/blog/xyzxyz` is going to `info.new.com/blog/xyzxyz`